# 504 gateway timeout magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a magento ecommerce store where admin panel is working fine but the frontend of the website is displaying the 504 gateway timeout - server didnt respond in time.

So please help me out with fixing this error.

Here is the url for front end : http://desireddesigns.in/shop

Back end url : http://desireddesigns.in/shop/admin

[image]

and sometimes i get the following error as shown in the figure.

Comment: try with, clear cache in magento

Comment: i tried by cleaning the cache as well as by clearing all the sessions... but didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an hosting issue i guess. First of all does your project work fine on local server, if yes visit this link :
https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/1284-mysql-server-has-gone-away
If its not working on local machine as well , please comment.

Comment: I configured everything in localhost as explained, but still shows the same error lines.